# Length of intersecting chords inside circle, given angle, vertex and circle radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's assume a circle with the known radius of **R** and origin **O**. We know the position of the intersection of two lines within that circle: vector **A**. Those lines both terminate at the perimeter of the circle and we know the value of the angle **a** between those lines, for simplicity let's assume *AB* is at a right angle (Y-up). How does one determine the length of line **CA** or just the position of **C** (Note that it is not necessarily at the same angle as **AO**).

I think this one is hard to explain without a picture so either bare with the crappy ASCII art.

```
          B  
   C..|''''..
  .'\ |      '.              B
 :   \|        :      C      |
:     A         :      \     |
:       O       :       \  a |
:               :        \.''|
 :             :          \  |
  '.         .'   CA = ?   \ |
    ''.....''               \|
                             A
```

Or see this image.

[image]

I will implement it with programming / scripting but need to figure out which method to use, I could "project" point **A** onto the circle if there's no better option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know the co-ordinates of $A$, then you can calculate the length $OA$ and the angle $CAO$, you can then the sine law to solve for the length $AC$

Comment: Exactly, which length do you want to know, $\pmb{AC}$ or $\pmb{CB}$? I am asking this because knowing $\pmb{CB}$ does not make things easy for you, when you are going to calculate the coordinates of the point $\pmb{C}$.

Comment: You are right, this was a typo and I meant **AC** (Will edit). I've implemented WW1's suggestion and it's working. I was a bit hesitant since the law of sines can give an ambiguous result for a SSA triangle, but not in this situation it seems. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

@WW1's comment pointed me in the right direction (I would upvote if I had the rep):

- Get the angle $\angle CAO$, use law of sines to get the length of **AC**.

The triangle **CAO** is a SSA triangle, so using the law of sines could give ambiguous results but the code I've implemented seems solid regardless of input. I don't know why but I guess that's another question in its own right. Here's a short [gif-animation](https://i.imgur.com/8HyuogL.gif) of the implementation.

My original question was a bit vague, so I'll just walk through the steps I used.

- The direction from **A** to **C** is known unit vector $\hat{AC}$
- We also know the values for unit vector $\hat{AO}$, and magnitude $|AO|$
- Magnitude $|CO| = \text{radius}$
- Get the (shortest) angle difference using the dot product:
  $$\angle CAO = \arccos(\hat{AC} \cdot \hat{AO})$$
- Get remaining angles of triangle **CAO**:
  $$\angle ACO = \arcsin(\frac{|AO| * \sin(\angle CAO)}{|CO|})$$
  $$\angle AOC = 180^{\circ} - \angle ACO - \angle CAO$$
- Get distance from **A** to **C**:
  $$|AC| = \frac{\sin(\angle AOC) * |CO|}{\sin(\angle CAO)}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Draw a radius from O parallel with AB. For point $A (x_A, y_A)$ We have:

$m=\tan(\widehat{AOD})=\dfrac {x_A}{y_A}$

$$ b=\widehat{AOD}=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x_A}{y_A}\right)$$

If $\widehat {BAC}=a$ is given the we have:

$c=\widehat {CAE}= a-b$

and:

$$OA=\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2}$$

finally:

$$CA\approx \frac{R-OA}{\cos c}$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the notation here, **BCA** should be **BAC**? But I feel like this is an approximation anyway since **CAE** is not necessarily a right triangle?

Comment: @neskid, You are right , corrected.

Answer (score 0):

[image: AC1]

Following formula can be also used to determine the length of $AC$ (see $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$)

$$AC=\sqrt{r^2-\left(x_A^2+y_A^2\right)\sin^2\left(\omega+\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x_A}{y_A}\right)\right)}-\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2}\cos \left(\omega+\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x_A}{y_A}\right)\right)$$

This formula gives the length of $AC$ for a point $A$ defined anywhere in the interior of a circle and two points $B$ and $C$ lying on its circumference making $\measuredangle BAC=\omega\enspace$ when measured counterclockwise from $B$ to $C$. $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$ to $\mathrm{Fig.\space 4\enspace}$ illustrate how $\angle BAC$ is defined. Furthermore, $x_A$ and $y_A$ are not signless lengths, but signed $x$- and $y$-Cartesian coordinates of $A$

[image: AC2]